# Passing a form as a reference into a class, but where should I call it from?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I'd like to pass my form as a reference into a class, so the class object can access public methods from the form. I've tried it in a few different places, but each one has a few limitations.

Is there a way to instantiate the class from outside of the events, but still pass in the form?

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //If I instantiate the class here, the form seemingly doesn't exist yet 
        //and can't be passed in using "this."
        Downloader downloader = new Downloader(this);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If I instantiate the class here, the form can be passed in, but the
            //class object can't be seen outside of this event.
            Downloader downloader = new Downloader(this);
        }

        private void downloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If I instantiate the class here, the form can be passed in, but the
            //class object can't be seen outside of this event.
            Downloader downloader = new Downloader(this);

            downloader.dostuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to look at [variable scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx). When you declare a variable in a Method it is visible only in that Method, In this case you need a Variable visible to the entire Class which the two answers below give you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. Change it to:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Downloader downloader;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.downloader = new Downloader(this);
        }

        private void downloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           downloader.Whatever();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! Just so I understand what is happening here, the downloader object is being treated as sort of a property of the form once it's instantiated, and then we replace the property by reinstantiating it?

Comment: @appski It's called a **class attribute**. C# introduced this "property" term that means an attribute + `get; set;`. The most usual place to instantiate a class attribute is at the **constructor**. However, since you're using it inside a `Form`, we can safely use the `Form_Load` like it was the ctor. This attribute will have the same lifetime as the object that contains it (that is, the form).

Comment: It is declaring `downloader` as a member field of class `Form1`. Without any sarcasm or anything, if you don't understand these things, you should probably pick up a book on C# or object oriented design and do some reading first. These are basics.

Comment: @AndreCalil It's not a class attribute, actually. It's a field. Attributes are something quite different.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I'm afraid you are not aware of the OO terminology. *Field* doesn't even exist. It's a class attribute.

Comment: @appski Yes, you are getting it. Declaration and assignment are different moments. As you have pointed at the question, we can't do them together because of the form lifetime, that's why we are breaking it into 2 steps. Due to the attribute's lifetime, you can safely use it inside methods and events, because it will exist as long as your form exists.

Comment: They call them "fields" in java, and I'm quite certain I've seen them referred to as "fields" in .NET, as well. And when C# has a very different construct called an "attribute", it muddies the water to call a member variable an "attribute", even if it conforms to a book or books that you read.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw That's why we should not addict to framework's specific terminology. What C# calls attribute, Java calls annotation. So what? However, if you do study about OO basics, you'll see that this variable is a *class attribute*.

Comment: *He's coding in C#*, and he's clearly a beginner. He's far more likely to come across the Framework's terminology on MSDN than he is the "OO basics" that you're clinging to. For a beginner, being told that a field is called an attribute becomes very confusing when they're also told that bracketed decorators are called attributes. I'm not debating your "OO basics", because it doesn't matter. They don't make it clearer for him to work in the space he's working in.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw He would be better off by learning the concepts and not "how to do it using this language". I face daily problems due to developers that don't know concepts, all they know is how to follow some big player specification. And it's not "my basics", if you had studied CC rather than English you would know it. I gave the right answer and a proper explanation, give a break.

Comment: It worked great, thanks @AndreCalil. I think the reason I was confused was that the Attribute/Field in question was another class, and the class it was being applied to was a form, where I hadn't seen this type of thing before. My understanding of the concept was a bit too specific eg `person.lastname` and things like that. I think this also clears up some confusion about how classes were declared.

Comment: @AndreCalil I will give you a break, and I apologize for going on about it. appski, I'll just say take note that when you encounter attributes in C#, they are something different. That isn't rendering Andre's answer invalid, but it could save you some confusion.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw That's right, happy that we agreed on something, after all. And it was kind of a pointeless discussion. Nice talking, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Downloader downloader;
        // either of the following two will work
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            downloader = new Downloader(this);
        }

        private void downloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            downloader = new Downloader(this);
        }
    }
}
```